# Why python interprets \\ as a "Bad escape"

Tags: python, python-re

Using the re library my problem is in this line

`x = re.match("([A-Z]:|home∼|\.\.?)\\", txt)`

Im trying to get a match with a disk "E:", "home∼", or a parent folder ".." followed by a backslash

The error goes as following:

> Exception has occurred: error
> bad escape (end of pattern) at position 20

Am i doing something wrong?
I think i´m doing something really dumb and don't realise it

Comment: You probably meant to use a raw string `r"([A-Z]:|home∼|\.\.?)\\"` - note the `r` at the start. Otherwise the actual string value has only a single backslash at the end.

Comment: Backslash is both a string escape and an RE escape. After the string parser converts double escape to single escape, there's nothing for the escape to escape when the RE parser processes it.

Comment: ```\\``` in a string literal gives you a ```\``` in your string. A ```\``` on its own in a regular expression is a bad escape because the regex engine doesn't know what you're trying to escape with it.